# Sending unicode characters from the clipboard using ClipGet()

Tags: unicode, autoit

So, currently I'm basically copying a name of the folder using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that I'm sending to a window explorer. The text that gets copied is usually full of Unicode characters. Then, I'm using `ClipGet()` like this:

```
$data = ClipGet()
Send($data)
```

Unfortunately, the `ClipGet()` command does not work well with Unicode, so instead of sending the correct title of the folder, I get a bunch of `?` characters. I'm really not sure what should I do to `Send()` the proper text filled with Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clip get works perfectly. Send() is the problem.

From the forum

```
;======================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SendUnicode("string")
; Description:    Send a unicode or an ASCII string.
; Parameter(s):  $string is the string you want to send.
; Requirement(s):   String Input.
; Return Value(s):  None
; Author(s):        Robie Zhou (robiezhou@gmail.com)
;
;======================================================
Func _SendUnicode($string)
    Local $char
    Local $code

    For $i = 1 to StringLen($string)
        $char = StringMid($string, $i, 1)
        $code = Asc($char)
        If $code > 127 Then
            $code = $code * 256
            $i  = $i + 1
            $char = StringMid($string, $i, 1)
            $code = $code + Asc($char)
        EndIf
        Send("{ASC " & $code & "}")
    Next
EndFunc
```